# How to create a copy of an element when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been trying to learn to build websites, and I've come to an issue I cannot seem to find the answer to. I would like #buttonNewNote to create a copy of #cloneBox when it is clicked, but I can't seem to figure out how. Thank you!

Code

```
      <html>
<body>
  <div id='navbar'>
    <div id='siteTitle'>
      <h1> Notes.com </h1>
      <button id= 'buttonNewNote'> New Note </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='cloneBox'>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50">Enter your notes Here! </textarea>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
 .cloneBox {
        top: 200px;
        left:50px;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        border: 5px;
        border-top: 20px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: yellow;
        width:260px;
    }

    #noteInput {
      position: relative;
      min-width: 50px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 5px;
      border-top: 20px;
      border-color:  #3296d2;
    }
```

What I have of the Jquery

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('.cloneBox').draggable();
  $('#buttonNewNote').click(function(){
    $(document.createElement('div'));
      $('div').html('<textarea rows="4" cols="50">Enter your notes Here! 
</textarea>')
      $('div').addClass('cloneBox')


  });
});
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: You need to use `clone()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**clone**](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#buttonNewNote').click(function() {
    $(".cloneBox").clone().appendTo("#cloneArea")
  });
});
```

```css
.cloneBox {
  top: 200px;
  left: 50px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  border: 5px;
  border-top: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: yellow;
  width: 260px;
}

#noteInput {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px;
  border-top: 20px;
  border-color: #3296d2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='navbar'>
  <div id='siteTitle'>
    <h1> Notes.com </h1>
    <button id='buttonNewNote'> New Note </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='cloneBox'>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50">Enter your notes Here! </textarea>
</div>
<div id="cloneArea"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using clone()

```
  $('#buttonNewNote').click(function(){
   var clone_box = $('body').find('.cloneBox:first');
   clone_box.clone().appendTo( "body" );
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `clone()` to get the clone of the `textarea` and append it to your DOM. And ensure that `textarea` doesn't clone the values, so you need to reset it. Below is updated code:

```js
$('#buttonNewNote').click(function() {
  var cloneObj = $(".cloneBox:first").clone();
  $(cloneObj).find('textarea').val('Enter your notes Here!');
  $('body').append(cloneObj);
});
```

```css
.cloneBox {
  top: 200px;
  left: 50px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  border: 5px;
  border-top: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: yellow;
  width: 260px;
}

#noteInput {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px;
  border-top: 20px;
  border-color: #3296d2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div id='navbar'>
    <div id='siteTitle'>
      <h1> Notes.com </h1>
      <button id='buttonNewNote'> New Note </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='cloneBox'>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50">Enter your notes Here! </textarea>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#buttonNewNote').click(function(){
    var div = $('.cloneBox').clone();
    var textArea = div.find('#textarea1').RemoveAttr('id');
    textArea.attr('id','textarea2');
    $('.cloneBox').append(textArea;
  });
});
```

and your html will be:

```
    <html>
<body>
  <div id='navbar'>
    <div id='siteTitle'>
      <h1> Notes.com </h1>
      <button id= 'buttonNewNote'> New Note </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='cloneBox'>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="textarea1">Enter your notes Here! </textarea>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to add only textarea else you have to append whole div in body.

Answer (score 0):

Changing as little as possible in your code for you to see what to do:

```
$('#buttonNewNote').click(function() {
    var note = document.createElement('div');
    $(note).html('<textarea rows="4" cols="50">Enter your notes Here! </textarea>');
    $(note).addClass('cloneBox');
    $(note).draggable();
    $('body').append(note);
});
```

But you should probably just take advantage of jQuery's `clone` function (note that you have to recall draggable):

```
$('#buttonNewNote').click(function() {
    $('body').append($($('.cloneBox')[0]).clone());
    $('.cloneBox').draggable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. For cloning elements though, I prefer to use the .clone() method, and then append that clone to the parent of the original element so that it occurs right after it in the HTML. I also added one more line to the bottom of the click function to reset the clone as also being draggable.

Don't forget to add both script tags so that you are using both jQuery and jQuery-UI.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  var copy = $('.cloneBox').clone();
  $('.cloneBox').draggable();
  $('#buttonNewNote').click(function(){
    $('.cloneBox:first').parent().append(copy.clone());
    $('.cloneBox').draggable();
  });
});
```

```css
 .cloneBox {
        top: 200px;
        left:50px;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        border: 5px;
        border-top: 20px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: yellow;
        width:260px;
    }

    #noteInput {
      position: relative;
      min-width: 50px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 5px;
      border-top: 20px;
      border-color:  #3296d2;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id='navbar'>
  <div id='siteTitle'>
    <h1> Notes.com </h1>
    <button id= 'buttonNewNote'> New Note </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='cloneBox'>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50">Enter your notes Here! </textarea>
</div>
```